# Merge two arrays while preserving the original array order

Tags: objective-c, arrays, ios

I've writing an application that requests data from an external source (Twitter), which is returned as an ordered array in chronological order:

**External array**

1. Item A (Latest)
2. Item B
3. Item C
4. Item D (Oldest)

I add these items to another array preserving the same order:

**My array**

1. Item A (Latest)
2. Item B
3. Item C
4. Item D (Oldest)

I then query the external source again and receive another array of new items, it looks like this:

**New External array**

1. Item E (Latest)
2. Item F
3. Item G
4. Item H

I add them to my array and get this:

**My array**

1. Item A
2. Item B
3. Item C
4. Item D (Oldest)
5. Item E (Latest)
6. Item F
7. Item G
8. Item H

The problem is that the external array data is sorted chronologically with the newest item first originally that was A, since doing an update that is now E. So you can see the ordering of the array is now wrong, what I need is:

**My array**

1. Item E (Latest)
2. Item F
3. Item G
4. Item H
5. Item A
6. Item B
7. Item C
8. Item D (Oldest)

My code currently looks something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
...
- (void)getDataFromExternalSource:(NSArray *)externalArray
{
for(NSDictionary *item in externalArray) {

    // Need loop so I can do some extra stuff here with each item object (not shown in this example.)
    [myArray addObject: item];
}   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *newArray = [externalArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:myArray];
[myArray release];
myArray = [newArray mutableCopy];
```

Any reason not to do this?

Comment: Exactly. If it were me I'd use a sorting method to be sure the newest were actually first, but this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the new array as the first array and add the old items after.

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:externalArray.count + myArray.count];
for(NSDictionary *item in externalArray) {

    // Need loop so I can do some extra stuff here with each item object (not shown in this example.)
    [newArray addObject: item];
}

[newArray addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the array as a stack, so the old items get pushed below the newer ones. You could achieve that by adding every element at the last position using `[myArray addObject:newObject];`. You will have to iterate backwards in the original array in order to insert them from oldest to newest. You can achieve that by doing :

```
for(NSUInteger index = [newArray count] - 1; i == 0; i--)
{
    NSDictionary*object = [newArray objectAtIndex:index];
    [myArray addObject:object];
}
```

This way you will get the array you need

Cheers

Comment: Would that not give me the same problem in reverse order? The latest item always needs to be at the top of the array and oldest at the bottom. I will then use this array to populate a UITableView, so it's important that they are in the order that they will be displayed on screen.

Comment: Essentially what I need to do is add any additional externalArrays to the top of the myArray i.e. stick them together.

Comment: @Camsoft, It should work now, by iterating the arrays backwards, assuming that they are chronologically ordered from newest to oldest, you ensure that you get the oldest first,nserting them at the last position of the array. So when you show that array, the newest are at the top and the oldest ones at the bottom.