# compaire NSArray items with every other item in the NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I have an NSArray of NSStrings and would like to know how to compare each item in the array with every other item in the array to see **if there is any strings different from the rest**.

I have seen a c++ example

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
    // compare list.get(i) and list.get(j)
  }
}
```

but was woundering if there is a better easier way in objective C? also the other thing I need to do is make sure the item doesn't compare itself while it loops through.

Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE ** **BOLD** is the updated part of the question **

Comment: Is identifying the paired strings what you want?

Comment: That seems right.  Note that you need `isEqualToString:` to match the **content** of items at `i` and `j`; `==` is an address comparison and is only guaranteed to match if they're both the same object.

Comment: oh crap I have just edited my question.. it was not supposed to be if there are any paring but the opposite. If one string is different from all the others then I mean to do something with that. That something will be a change in height of a uitableview cell as if every string in the array is the same then i will display one value at the top of the view, else if one value is different I will display each in respective value in their tableviewcells.. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Simplest would be to insert them all into a HashSet (er, make that NSMutableSet).

Comment: @HurkNburkS Apologies to you; I think I was altogether wet in my response.

Comment: thats all good no worries :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you want the strings that only appear once in the list, correct?

```
NSCountedSet *counted = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:list];
for (NSString *string in counted) {
    NSUInteger count = [counted countForObject:string];
    if (count == 1) {
        // process "string", it appears in the list just once
    }
}
```

If you just want to know if there is more than one different value in the list then do this:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:list];
if (set.count == 1) {
    // There is only one distinct value in the list
} else {
    // There is more than one distinct value in the list
}
```

Comment: nice, I'm just wondering about the scenario where you have 2 instance variables x and y and you do x=@"apple"; y=@"apple" and add them to list. Then the set would most probably count them as distinct since the pointers point to different memory addresses. I think the safest way is to use nested for loops using string isEqualTo

Comment: @KaanDedeoglu No, If you add `x` and `y` to the set, there will still only be one instance of the string `@"apple"` in the set. That's the point of a set. Any values where `isEqual:` returns `YES` will only appear in the set once.

Comment: cool, that's what I was wondering. So is it true to say that in sets the equality checks are made using isEqual: method of NSObject rather than a simple == check?

Comment: Yes, this is true. Using `==` wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an NSMutableDictionary. This is very similar to "merging two lists into unique values", the apple docs actually explain the complicated way somewhere. I forgot where I found it, but the easy way is here: [Merge two arrays while preserving the original array order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815695/merge-two-arrays-while-preserving-the-original-array-order)

So what you'd do is loop through everything, see if there's a key (set to the string), if not, add one via the setObject: forKey: method, then enumerate through the dictionary or just grab the allKeys value after.

Answer (score 0):

Use two sets.  If the string goes into the first set without conflict, add it to the second set.  If the string encounters a conflict in the first set, remove it from the second set.  When you've processed all the strings the second set contains the unique ones.