# two array retrive both value in one first array

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

`First_mutableArray` is `1,2,3,4,5,6`
`Second_MutableArray` is `2,4,6,8,0,12`

How to get output like this

`First_mutableArray` is `1,2,3,4,5,6,8,0,12` ?

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815695/merge-two-arrays-while-preserving-the-original-array-order

Comment: Is there a possibility to have duplicate values in any of the arrays? Do you need unique values in your 'merged' array? Is the order important?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ordered version:

```
    NSMutableOrderedSet *first = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",nil];
    NSOrderedSet *second = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:@"2",@"4",@"6",@"8",@"0",@"12",nil];
    [first unionOrderedSet:second];
```

Variable **first** will contain the result.

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
NSMutableArray *first=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6"]];
NSMutableArray *second=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"2",@"4",@"6",@"8",@"0",@"12"]];

for (id obj in second) {
    if (![first containsObject:obj]) {
        [first addObject:obj];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",first);
```

---

EDIT:

```
NSMutableArray *first=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6"]];
NSMutableArray *second=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"2",@"4",@"6",@"8",@"0",@"12"]];


NSMutableOrderedSet *firstSet=[NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:first];
NSOrderedSet *secondSet=[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:second];

[firstSet unionOrderedSet:secondSet];
first=[[firstSet array] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"%@",first);
```

**Credit goes to Mark Kryzhanouski*

Comment: Less efficient than using an NSSet

Comment: @ElJay: Yes this is very less efficient than Mark's solution. :)

Comment: Yeah, Mark's solution is better than mine :), although it ordered 0 wrong.

Answer (score 0):

combine those two array and use below code on combinedArray two remove duplicates.

```
NSMutableArray* combinedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];
[combinedArray addObjectsFromArray: secondArray];
NSMutableArray *myUniqueArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (id obj in combinedArray) {
    if (![myUniqueArray containsObject:obj]) {
        [myUniqueArray addObject:obj];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6", nil];
     NSMutableArray *array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"2",@"4",@"6",@"8",@"0",@"12", nil];
    for(int i = 0;i<array1.count;i++)
    {
        NSString *str = [array1 objectAtIndex:i];
        if (![array containsObject:str])
        {
            [array addObject: str]; 
        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"contins");
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[NSMutableSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html)** for doing this stuff:

```
NSMutableSet *firstSet  = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:First_mutableArray];
NSMutableSet *secondSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:Second_MutableArray];
[firstSet unionSet:secondSet];
NSArray *uniqueArray    = [firstSet allObjects];
```

Comment: Looked elegant but it will give 6,4,2. Also nsset will loose the order as in array. You need to use NSOrderedSet/or its mutable counterpart

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: thanks for the comment :) That was a typo ! Fixed that

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go.  Using an NSSet will give you better performance than iterating over each array and adding objects that don't match.

```
NSArray *arr1 = @[@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6];
NSArray *arr2 = @[@2,@4,@6,@8,@0,@12];

NSMutableSet *set = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithArray:arr1];
[set addObjectsFromArray:arr2];

// Unsorted
NSLog(@"set = %@", [set description]);

// Sorted
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [set sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
NSLog(@"sortedArray = %@", [sortedArray description]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one :

```
NSMutableArray *first=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6"]];
NSMutableArray *second=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"2",@"4",@"6",@"8",@"0",@"12"]];

NSMutableSet *firstSet  = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:first];
NSMutableSet *secondSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:second];
[firstSet unionSet:secondSet];
NSArray *uniqueArray    = [firstSet allObjects];
```